# Selecting the optgroup label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using javascript to display a list of options, it looks a bit like this

```
<select>
   <optgroup label="OPEN">
      <option value=1>state 1</option>
      <option value=1>state 2</option>
      <option value=1>state 3</option>
   </optgroup>
   <optgroup label="CLOSED">
      <option value=1>X state Error</option>
      <option value=1>Y state error</option>
      <option value=1>Z state error</option>
   </optgroup>
</select>
```

The problems here represent the states of DB records.
My problem is that my labels are not selectable, I can only select the available options within the LABEL, I want the user to be able to SELECT the labels OPEN and CLOSED, eg if he clicks on OPEN, I want to display all the records in the OPEN state. 
Considering that i'm new to javascript, jquery, html  and css, google could not help me.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That is not possible. The only job of the element is to group options - not to be interacted with by the user. You could replace them with `option` elements, and take care of the formatting (bold text for fake “option”, indented text for the other options) yourself ...

Comment: you need a dropdown menu?

Comment: What you want is not possible with regular HTML form elements. You can to one of two things: **1)** Use some sort of UI library that replaces regular HTML input elements with enhanced versions. **2)** Use normal HTML elements and re-think your approach. A flat list of all available states will be *much* easier to use than one where the user has to click multiple times to select a single entry. I suggest you go with option 2.